# Power BI now showing total

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

so, I have a dataset of some positions with expire date
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjPv8.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiFb0.png, and I want to count just the rows where the date appear just one time, like position `no.2` and position `no. 4`, and the measure that I tried is this

`Measure = IF(COUNT(Sheet1[position])<2,CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[position]),Sheet1[year]=2022)`

and I put this measure into a table and it doesn't show the total. [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG5VE.png)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I try to reproduce your way, if you create the measure function, then
  put the all variable into table will show like this

  [image]

  but the measure will take all position to be the single one.
- Infer what you want is showing all columns and could get only **count position<2**,
  so I recommend to create table column, and the result could show all values.
  [image]
  [image]